# Is This Code Efficient - Or is there a better way?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query

I have a RECIPE WP site, that is using CPTs to handle the recipe content.

The client wanted an A-Z Directory listing of all recipes.  I came to Wordpress Answers and found the following code that does what I wanted:

```
add_shortcode('recipe_list', 'recipe_query');
function recipe_query($atts, $content){
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'recipes',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$dl = '';
$glossary_letter = '';
$active_letters = array( );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$query->the_post();
$term_letter = strtoupper( substr( get_the_title(), 0, 1 ) );
if ( $glossary_letter != $term_letter ) {
    $dl .= (count( $active_letters ) ? '</ul>' : '') . '<li id="' . $term_letter . '"><span class="subheading">' . $term_letter . '</span><ul>';
    $glossary_letter = $term_letter;
    $active_letters[] = $term_letter;
}
$dl .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

}
$dl .= '</ul></li>';

$ul = '<ul class="letters">';
foreach ( array( '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' ) as $letter ) {
    $ul .= '<li>' . (in_array( $letter, $active_letters ) ? '<a href="#' . $letter . '">' . $letter . '</a>' : $letter) . '</li>';
}
$ul .= '</ul>';

return '<div id="glossary">' . $ul . '<ul class="definitions">' . $dl . '</ul></div>';
}
```

Right now there are 1020 recipes and it seems to run slower than the other pages and since I'm a frankenstein coder (some from here and some from there) - I decided to ask the real php coders.  **Is there a better, more efficient way to write the code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend caching - generating the HTML mark-up and storing that in a cache, and using that rather then generating the list on each page load.

Of course, the cache would have to cleared if a recipe is ever added, removed or changes title.

```
add_shortcode('recipe_list', 'recipe_query');
function recipe_query( $atts, $content ){

     //Get mark-up from cache (if present)
     $html = get_transient( 'wpse123038_recipe_list' );

     if( !$html ){
          //Nothing in cache - generate mark-up
          $html = '';
          ....

          //Store in cache (for a long time - a year?)
          set_transient( 'wpse123038_recipe_list', $html, 60*60*24*365 );     
     }

     return $html;
}
```

Now everytime we add/remove a post (or may be its published and then we set it to 'draft') - basically anytime it might go from *not being* in the list, to *being* on the list :). (Note, you'll also want to clear the cache whenever the recipe title changes...)

```
function wpse123038_recipe_status_changes( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    //Check if status has changed
    if( $new_status == $old_status ){
        return;
    }

    //Check post type
    if( 'recipes' != get_post_type( $post) ){
         return;
    }

    //Check if we're publishing on 'unpublishing' it.
    if( 'publish' == $new_status || 'publish' == $old_status ){
         delete_transient( 'wpse123038_recipe_list' );

         //For bonus points, regenerate the cache here :)
    }

}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse123038_recipe_status_changes', 10, 3 );
```

So when ever a recipe is published, or is 'unpublished' the cache is cleared. This means the next visitor will have to wait for the mark-up to be generated again.

Of course, we're usually less concerned about page load times admin-side, so when the cache is cleared, you could regenerate it then. Giving a (usually) seamless experience on the front-end.

Comment: So, I understand what you're saying, but how do I integrate the code that generates the listing and the cache code?  Do I remove the shortcode from the function that creates the list and add your code with the shortcode?

Comment: Your `recipe_query()` function currently generates the HTML mark-up, you want that inside teh `//Nothing in cache - generate mark-up` conditional. It generate the mark-up and assign it to `$html`.

Comment: Stephen, I've tried modifying the code and I get a white screen.  Is there any chance, you'd give me the code combined into one to replace my original code?